# Extjs-3.4 Checkbox in specified column of checkbox group

Tags: extjs, checkbox, extjs3

I am using ExtJS-3.4 ,in which I need to show the checkboxgroup with 9 checkboxes and I am able to show the checkboxes in checkboxgroups with two columns.
The two column controls(checkboxes) were distributed automatically in the checkboxgroup columns.

```
{
                    xtype:'checkboxgroup',
                    id:'randomId',
                    fieldLabel: 'CheckboxGroupLabel',
                    autoScroll:false,
                    labelSeparator : '',
                    columns: 2,
                    items: [
                      {
                        boxLabel: "CB1", 
                        name: "CB1".toLowerCase(),
                        id:'CheckBoxId1'
                       }
                      .....
                       {
                        boxLabel: "CB9", 
                        name: "CB9".toLowerCase(),
                        id:'CheckBoxId9'
                       }
                     ]
}
```

Now I need to show checkbox1 to checkbox6 in column 1 of checkboxgroup 
and from checkbox7 to checkbox9 in column 2 of checkboxgroup.

Is the above case could be possible ? Please help on this if anyone have come across this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved exactly that by using the `vertical` config and some invisible dummy checkboxes:

```
                vertical: true,
                items: [
                  {
                    boxLabel: "CB1", 
                    name: "CB1".toLowerCase(),
                    id:'CheckBoxId1'
                   }
                  .....
                   {
                    boxLabel: "CB9", 
                    name: "CB9".toLowerCase(),
                    id:'CheckBoxId9'
                   },
                   {
                    style:'visibility:hidden'
                   },
                   {
                    style:'visibility:hidden'
                   },
                   {
                    style:'visibility:hidden'
                   }
                 ]
```